# Why is gulp.watch not firing?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

gulp.watch is not firing ( at least it seems like that )

i tried diffrent patterns for the watch input

```
var src = './css/main.css';

gulp.task('deploy', () => {
return gulp.src(src)
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 10 versions', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'ie 10'))
    .pipe(concat('default.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});

gulp.task('upload', () => {
    var conn = getFtpConnection();
    return gulp.src('./**/default.css', { base: '.', buffer: false })
        .pipe(conn.newer(remoteLocation))
        .pipe(conn.dest(remoteLocation));
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
gulp.watch(src, gulp.series('deploy', 'upload'));

});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch'));
```

i expect the output to be 
starting 'deploy'...
finished 'deploy'
starting 'upload' ...
finished 'upload'

but the actual output is nothing

when i change and save './css/main.css' nothing happens

```
[15:55:01] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\Work\testproject2\gulpfile.js
[15:55:01] Starting 'default'...
[15:55:01] Starting 'watch'...
```

i dont know what is responisble for this behaviour and need some ideas on how to solve this problem.